# Laravel polymorph relation query looking for the wrong column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-5

I'm trying to create my first polymorphic relationship and have followed the documentation on the website and checked with several tutorials online that all follow a similar theme. I have 3 tables, Pages, Menu and Menu Items. Menu items will always be a child of Menu, and will either be a page (in the case of a link) or another menu (in the case of a sub-menu). My tables are:

**Pages**

```
+----+------+----------+------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+
| id | name | url_slug | file | layout | seo_title | seo_description | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at |
+----+------+----------+------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

**Menus**

```
+----+------+------------+------------+
| id | name | created_at | updated_at |
+----+------+------------+------------+
```

**Menu Items**

```
+----+---------+-------------+---------------+-------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| id | menu_id | itemable_id | itemable_type | label | left | right | created_at | updated_at |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------+-------+------+-------+------------+------------+
```

So for menu items table the `menu_id` is the parent of the menu item, it has a one to many relationship with the menus table. `itemable_id` and `itemable_type` are used in the polymophic relation, `itemable_id` should reference the `id` column in either Menus or Pages depending on what `itemable_type` is, which will be the Menu or Page model.

To create this relationship I've added methods to my models like this:

**Page**

```
/**
 * Fetch the menu items this page is linked to.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
 */
public function menuItems()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Modules\Menu\Models\MenuItem', 'itemable');
}
```

**Menu**

```
/**
 * Fetch all child menu items belonging to this menu.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function childItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Modules\Menu\Models\MenuItem');
}

/**
 * Fetch all menu items linked to this menu.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
 */
public function menuItems()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Modules\Menu\Models\MenuItem', 'itemable');
}
```

**Menu Item**

```
/**
 * Fetch the menu this item belongs to.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function menu()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Modules\Menu\Models\Menu');
}

/**
 * Fetch the models this menu item links to.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo
 */
public function itemable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

I've created all the tables and I'm now trying to seed them. My seed looks like this:

```
public function run()
{
    $menu = Menu::create([
        'name' => 'Main'
    ]);

    foreach ( [
                  [
                      'page_id' => 1,
                      'label' => 'Home',
                      'left' => 1,
                      'right' => 2
                  ],
                  [
                      'page_id' => 2,
                      'label' => 'About Us',
                      'left' => 3,
                      'right' => 4
                  ]
              ] as $arr )
    {
        /* @var $page Page */
        $page = Page::findOrFail($arr['page_id']);
        $item = new MenuItem($arr);
        $page->menuItems()->save($item);
        $item->menu()->associate($menu);
    }
}
```

But I keep getting errors when I run it about the `page_id` column not existing. The exact error is

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'page_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `menu_items` (`page_id`, `label`, `left`, `right`, `itemable_type`, `itemable_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, Home, 1, 2, App\Models\Page, 1, 2016-08-03 12:32:21, 2016-08-03 12:32:21))
```

Everything about the query is fine, except it's trying to populate `page_id` as well as the itemable columns. Why is it doing this? How can I get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `page_id` to `itemable_id`

```
[
  'page_id' => 1, //change this to itemable_id
  'label' => 'Home',
  'left' => 1,
  'right' => 2
],
[
  'page_id' => 2, //change this to itemable_id
  'label' => 'About Us',
  'left' => 3,
  'right' => 4
]
```

Because in following line ,

```
$item = new MenuItem($arr);
```

When you are trying to insert the the `$arr` in MenuItem it is expecting `itemable_id` and not `page_id`

So your updated code would be like this:

```
public function run()
{
    $menu = Menu::create([
        'name' => 'Main'
    ]);

    foreach ( [
                  [
                      'itemable_id' => 1,
                      'label' => 'Home',
                      'left' => 1,
                      'right' => 2
                  ],
                  [
                      'itemable_id' => 2,
                      'label' => 'About Us',
                      'left' => 3,
                      'right' => 4
                  ]
              ] as $arr )
    {
        /* @var $page Page */
        $page = Page::findOrFail($arr['itemable_id']);
        $item = new MenuItem($arr);
        $page->menuItems()->save($item);
        $item->menu()->associate($menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh >.<, because I have a fillable array I didn't think it would take page_id from the array. It didn't even occur to me it could be that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're `menu_items` column doesn't contain any  `page_id` column and when you're trying to seed you're trying to store new data into a `menu_items` and it's gonna check each column from the `file_list` with your destination table which is here `menu_items` and it contains

Menu Items

```
+----+---------+-------------+---------------+-------+------+-------+------------+------------+
| id | menu_id | itemable_id | itemable_type | label | left | right | created_at | updated_at |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------+-------+------+-------+------------+--
```

So rename the column to `itemable_id` like so

```
foreach ( [
              [
                  'itemable_id' => 1,
                  'label' => 'Home',
                  'left' => 1,
                  'right' => 2
              ],
              [
                  'itemable_id' => 2,
                  'label' => 'About Us',
                  'left' => 3,
                  'right' => 4
              ]
          ] as $arr )
{
    /* @var $page Page */
    $page = Page::findOrFail($arr['itemable_id']);
```